# How to format value(number) stored in request attribute in JSP using struts 2 tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Below is my code for formatting number:

1) struts.xml

```
<struts>

        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="cvformat" />

        <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="format" class="com.sample.test.FormatAction">
                <result name="success">/sample.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
 </struts>
```

2) cvformat.properties

```
number.format = {0,number,#,##0.00}
```

3)FormatAction

```
package com.sample.test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

public class FormatAction implements ServletRequestAware {

    private double amount;

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public String execute() {

        amount = 18964.8953;
        request.setAttribute("temp", amount);

        return "success";
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

4) sample.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NUMBER FORMAT EXAMPLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Amount =  <s:property value="amount"></s:property><br/><br/>
        1) Formating amount(with format hard coded)  = <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{amount})"/><br/>
        2) Formating amount(with format fetched from properties file)  = <s:property value="getText('number.format',{amount})"/><br/>
        3) Formating amount set in request attribute(with format hard coded) = <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',#request.temp)"/><br/>
        4) Formating amount set in request attribute(with format fetched from properties file) = <s:property value="getText('number.format',#request.temp)"/><br/>
    </body>

</html>
```

5) Output

```
Amount = 18964.8953

1) Formating amount(with format hard coded) = 
2) Formating amount(with format fetched from properties file) = 18,964.90
3) Formating amount set in request attribute(with format hard coded) = 18964.8953
4) Formating amount set in request attribute(with format fetched from properties file) = {0,number,#,##0.00}
```

As seen in the output above, only instance variable value is getting formatted with pattern stored in properties file.

1. Why value stored in request attribute is not getting formatted?
2. Why instance variable value is not getting formatted when pattern
       is hardcoded in the JSP?

Please let me know how to format a value stored in request attribute in the JSP.

Comment: You forgot to wrap `#request.temp` in `{}` -> `getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}', {#request.temp})`. Works fine for me.

Comment: One format is better than two formats, goto `struts.custom.i18n.resources`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrapped #request.temp in {}. Case 2 and Case 4 (formatting with pattern picked from struts.custom.i18n.resources) are working fine but when it is not working when pattern is harcoded in the jsp. Anyway I will follow struts.custom.i18n.resources format.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: Woks for me. Which S2 version you are using?

Comment: I am using struts2-core-2.3.24.jar.